# 2D correlation function of image with itself gives wrong value

Tags: python, image, opencv, scipy, correlation

I am trying to find the relative shift in two microscope images since my sample shifts between frames.
This code is used to find the 2D correlation between two images. I then use this correlation array and determine where the maximum is and use that to shift two translated images, but I get a finite shift value even for the same image. Second snippet is the translation value code.

```
from scipy.signal.signaltools import correlate2d as c2d
import cv2
def cross_image_3(im1, im2):
    im1 = cv2.normalize(im1, None, alpha = 0, beta = 65535, norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype = cv2.CV_16U)
    im2 = cv2.normalize(im2, None, alpha = 0, beta = 65535, norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype = cv2.CV_16U)
    c12 = c2d(im1, im2, mode='same', boundary='symm')
    return c12
```

```
img_centre = np.array([*np.shape(mycamera.frames[0])])/2
shift = np.zeros((n, 2))
for i in range(n):
    corr_img = cross_image(mycamera.frames[0], mycamera.frames[i])
    corr_centre = np.asarray([*np.unravel_index(np.argmax(corr_img), corr_img.shape)])
#     print('Brightest spot in corr', corr_centre)
#     print('Center of image', img_centre)
#     print('Shift in pixels', img_centre - corr_centre)
    shift[i] = img_centre - corr_centre
print(shift)
```

Comment: It looks like your "img_centre" is the middle of the image resolution (np.shape/2) vs the "corr_centre" which is the the brightest spot on the image (np.argmax). Doesn't it make sense that the shift would be non-zero even with the same image?

Comment: I believe correlate2d correlates two images by convoluting one with the flipped in both axis image of the other. This way the centre should give the maximum correlation, hence the shift calculation. Thank you for your comment, got me thinking.